# self-hosted CI/CD runners and agents with Azure Container Apps jobs is failing with error "Job has reached the specified backoff limit"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cicd, azure-container-apps, azure-container-app-jobs

I'm trying to run CI/CD runners and agents with Azure Container Apps jobs as per the microsoft documentation -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/tutorial-ci-cd-runners-jobs?tabs=bash&pivots=container-apps-jobs-self-hosted-ci-cd-azure-pipelines

When I'm trying to run a placeholder job , the job is failing with error "Job has reached the specified backoff limit" , there are no further or detailed logs to see where it is failing.

Github repo for creating docker image and startup script is https://github.com/Azure-Samples/container-apps-ci-cd-runner-tutorial/blob/main/Dockerfile.azure-pipelines

Please anyone faced this issue guide me!!

Comment: most likely the container can't start. are you sure about the pat and org url ? can you check these are defined and with the desired values

Comment: yes pat token and organisation url were correct.Though i managed to solve the issue by building image from a linux machine. The issue i was facing while using docker image which was build on mac. Issue was with the script was not compatible with arm based architecture.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a job using this code

```
az containerapp job create -n "$PLACEHOLDER_JOB_NAME" -g "$RESOURCE_GROUP" --environment "$ENVIRONMENT" \
    --trigger-type Manual \
    --replica-timeout 300 \
    --replica-retry-limit 1 \
    --replica-completion-count 1 \
    --parallelism 1 \
    --image "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_NAME.azurecr.io/$CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME" \
    --cpu "2.0" \
    --memory "4Gi" \
    --secrets "personal-access-token=$AZP_TOKEN" "organization-url=$ORGANIZATION_URL" \
    --env-vars "AZP_TOKEN=secretref:personal-access-token" "AZP_URL=secretref:organization-url" "AZP_POOL=$AZP_POOL" "AZP_PLACEHOLDER=1" "AZP_AGENT_NAME=placeholder-agent" \
    --registry-server "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_NAME.azurecr.io"
```

You define there `--replica-retry-limit 1`. The error you got just says that you reached that limit. So you could try increase it. However, the issue probably is somewhere else. Please check logs in Azure Portal, maybe there you will find a reason why your job failed.

Comment: In the Monitoring section, please click on execution history and then click on console log for a particular run.

Comment: sample application ran but still ci/cd agent runners are faiiling,I checked system logs from execution history it says "Reason_s : Backofflimitexceeded and log_s: Job has reached the specified backoff limit"            Image is successfully pulled but when cotainer starts it fails with above error.
I can't see anything in console logs.
Container app environment log stream shows :  "UTC","Type":"Warning","ContainerAppName":"","RevisionName":"","ReplicaName":"","Msg":"Job has reached the specified backoff limit","Reason":"BackoffLimitExceeded","EventSource":"ContainerAppController","Count":1}"

Comment: I changed base image from ubuntu:20.04 to ubuntu to use latest image and now in console logs of execution history it is giving Log_s "exec  ./start.sh: exec format error". Shebang is present at start of the script and script permission is also correct i.e "RUN chmod +x start.sh" inside docker file